# Is there a CIL (Mono) library for using the Messaging Menu?

Tags: 10.10, indicator, mono

I know that `libappindicator0.1-cil-dev` is used for Application Indicators, but it doesn't seem capable of using the Messaging Menu. Am I missing something, or is there a different library I should be using?

I don't know of any Mono applications that use the Messaging Menu. Is there not yet a CIL library capable of using the it?

I'm running the Ubuntu 10.10 beta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `libindicate-gtk0.1-cil`

Answer (score 3):

There is now a mono application that uses the messaging menu: [Smuxi](http://www.smuxi.org/main/) (as of 0.8).  This is available in Ubuntu 10.10.